Remove last already printed to console line in Powershell
I am calling a command like this:
Write-Host 'Calling myScript... ' -NoNewline

Invoke-Expression '& .\myScript.bat arg1 arg2 arg3'

If ($LASTEXITCODE -eq 0) { Write-Host 'done' }
Else                     { Write-Host '`nERROR' }

I need to be able to both give command line arguments and to have access to $LASTEXISTCODE
.\myScript.bat can either produce an error output (which I want to see if it occurs) or, if all is ok, it seems to only produce a single newline as output. (unfortunately I cannot look deeper into myScript.bat because it calls a large project developed by another team, so I have to work around these empirical observations)
When no error occurs I do not want to remain with that newline in the middle of my output, I want the 'done' to be printed on the same line as the 1st Write-Host (and only the ERROR to be printed on a new line if it happens)
So essentially I need to "go back" to the previous line, "delete" the line that was created by the newline printed when myScript.bat executed with no error.
My goal is to maybe get something like this:
Write-Host 'Calling myScript... ' -NoNewline

Invoke-Expression '& .\myScript.bat arg1 arg2 arg3'

If ($LASTEXITCODE -eq 0) { SetCursorToPreviousLine ; Write-Host 'done' }
Else                     { Write-Host '`nERROR' }


Assign the output from invoking the batch script to a variable, then output it after testing $LASTEXITCODE
$batResults = & .\myScript.bat arg1 arg2 arg3 *>&1

if ($LASTEXITCODE) {
  Write-Host "`nERROR!"
  $batResults |ForEach-Object { Write-Host $_ -ForegroundColor Red }
}
else {
  Write-Host "Done!" -ForegroundColor Green
}


any specific reason to use only & and not Invoke-Expression?

I'd turn the question around: why in the world would you use Invoke-Expression here? :)

I was under the, evidently mistaken, impression Invoke-Expression was also used with shell\batch commands.

@sirtao You absolutely can - there's just no need for it, the command processor already knows how to invoke batch scripts :)

so using Invoke-Expression is basically adding overhead and, aside output stream management shenanigans, it's mostly to be used in the pipeline?

@sirtao Correct, best case it's a no-op, worst case it adds wallclock overhead - not to mention making your code less maintainable: characters that are a structural part of your code now gets treated as string literals by your editors.
